# Backbone.js: Using Embeded Javascript inside the View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to make the View dynamic as when someone touches the item, but using the '<%= myClassName %>' inside the View doesn't work. I can't use this technique inside the HTML file as it would draw another element and that's not the idea. Also I have set a template but it has nothing on it. I just did that to relate jQuery Mobile into a `data-role="content"` and render the view inside the content. Any ideas?

Here is what I have:

app.js

```
var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({  
    toggleStatus: function(){
        if(this.get('status') === 'incomplete'){
          this.set({'status': 'complete'});

        } else {
          this.set({'status': 'incomplete'});
        }

        this.save();
        // PUT /TODOS/1
    } 
});

var TodoItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TodoItem,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("button"),

    initialize: function () {
        this.on('remove', this.hideModel, this);
    },

    hideModel: function (model) {
        model.trigger('hide');
    }

});

var TodosView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
    },

    addOne: function (todoItem) {
        var todoView = new TodoView({ model: todoItem });
        this.$el.append(todoView.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function () {
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this); 
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
        this.addAll;
        return this;
    }
});

var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',

    // THIS IS THE MAIN PROBLEM 
    className: '<%= status %>',
    // END COMMENT 

    template: _.template( $('#personTemplate').html() ),

    events: {
        "touchstart": "toggleStatus",
        "touchend": "toggleStatus"
    },

    toggleStatus: function () {
        this.model.toggleStatus();
    },

    remove: function(){
        this.$el.remove();
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
        this.model.on('hide', this.remove, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));

        return this;
    }
});


var todoItems = new TodoItems([
    {
        description: 'Jeffrey Way',
        status: "incomplete",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        description: 'John Doe',
        status: "incomplete",
        id: 2
    },
    {
        description: 'Sally Doe',
        status: "incomplete",
        id: 3
    }
]);

var todosView = new TodosView({ 
    el: $('#elem'),
    collection: todoItems
});
todosView.render().el
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
this.$el.addClass(this.model.get('status'))
```

inside the view's `render` method.

Trying to use a template value in the view code doesn't make any sense; those properties are set when the object is parsed, so how would it know which object to fetch the `status` from?

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do is to toggle the className when the touch/touchend event fires. I just showed this mistake for making more clear what I'm trying to do. I have tried your answer but it won't work with the toggle event. Any other thoughts?

Comment: So put this line inside the `toggleStatus` method. I'm still confused about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    ...})
    var x=new TodoView ({className:'sample'});
```

Solution 2

Use a template!

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
template="<span class=<%-className%>>Some Stuff Goes Here</span>",
...
render:function(){
var $ele=$(_.template(this.template,{className:'sample'}));
  this.$el.replaceWith($ele);
  this.$el=$ele;
  this.delegateEvents();  //inbuilt-method, to re-bind all event handlers
});
```

Comment: This won't work as it will draw a `<div>` for each span element. What I'm trying to do is to use the model as a classname inside the default View.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing todo, if i understand correctly, is to listen to the change:status in your view, and adding/removing a class to your view according to the value of status.

in your initialize of TodoView:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:status', this.changeStatus);
```

in your TodoView declare:

```
changeStatus : function(model, value, options)
{
// add a class or toggle it or change something in the view..
}
```